# Showing $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{12}$ is a homomorphism and determining it's $Ker(\phi)$ and $Im(\phi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

**Question:** Group Theory:  Let $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{12}$ be defined by $$\phi(x) = x\;(\text{mod}\; 12)$$

**a).** Show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

My work: Let $\phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{12}$ be defined by $\phi(x)$ = $x$ $mod$ $12$

$\phi(x+y)$ $=$ $[x+y]_{12}$ $=$ $[x]_{12}$ $+$ $[y]_{12}$ $=$ $\phi(x)$ $+$ $\phi(y)$

$\therefore$ $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

---

**b).** Find $Ker(\phi)$ and $Im(\phi)$

My work: $Ker(\phi)$ $=$ {$x \in \mathbb Z$ $|   \phi(x) = [0]_{12}$}
                     $=$ {$x \in \mathbb Z$ $|$$[x]_{12} = [0]_{12}$}
                     $=$ {$x \in \mathbb Z$ $|$ $12$ divides $x$}
                     $=$ $12\mathbb Z$

$Im(\phi)$ $=$ {$\phi(x) \in \mathbb Z_{12} / x \in \mathbb Z$} $=$ $\mathbb Z_{12}$

Is my reasoning correct? I am unsure if my intuition is correct. Any help, comments, concerns, appreciated!

Comment: For part $(a)$ I would say that you did not really show anything. Why is $[x+y]_{12}=[x]+[y]$? As for finding the kernel, I think that you are all good. Maybe a word: $[x]=[0]$ if there exists an integer $n$ so that  $12 \cdot n=x$. For finding the image, I think that's fine.

Comment: You might want to mention this is in the context of group theory in the question, not just the tags. It took me a little while to spot that, and the same question would have different answers for, say, a ring homomorphism.

Comment: I hate to be that guy but, you haven't proved that $\phi$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you asking since you've not explained 'where we are at'.
So the answer here will be general, forgetting all group theory and only assuming an understanding of equivalence relations.

Fact 1: The relation $x \equiv y \text{ (mod 12) }$ is an equivalence relation, which by definition means that $x - y$ is divisible by $12$.

The block containing $0$ is equal to the set $\{\dots,-36,-24,-12,0,12,24,36,\dots \}$; we denote this set by $12\mathbb Z$ and the [quotient set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Quotient_set) by

$\tag 1 \mathbb Z \text{/} 12\mathbb Z$

General theory tells us that we have a [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Projection) (or quotient) mapping

$\tag 2 \phi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \text{/} 12\mathbb Z$

The projection is by definition a surjective mapping.

Notice that $0$ gets mapped to $12\mathbb Z \in \mathbb Z \text{/} 12\mathbb Z$, and of course $\phi(x) =  12\mathbb Z$ just means that $x \in 12\mathbb Z $.

So this takes care of the questions on the image and the kernel without having to know any group theory.